# how to play video from same point in full landscape mode when videoview is in ListView android?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am working on a app where I have list of videos shown in a Listview. And that Listview contains videoview to play video in the ListView itself.
(Note: I have restricted the screen mode to Portrait only)

When I try to play video in VideoView inside a ListView, it is working without any trouble. But what I actually want to achieve is, while the video is playing in videoView inside a Listview and if the user changes the screen mode to Landscape then video should be visible in fullscreen in landscape and start from the same point which it was while playing in Portrait mode.

Please help me out
Thanks

Comment: any code you tried so far you could show us?

Comment: yes I tried onConfiguration changed listener, but it won't work if I restrict the screen to portrait only. And I want it to be portrait only, but to go in Landscape when the video is playing specifically. Just like Youtube does.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ConfigurationChanged` method of Activity.

You may put your `VideoView` in `RelativeLayout`

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        switchToFullScreen();
     }
    }
}

     private void switchToFullScreen(){
     RelativeLayout mContainer = (RelativeLayout) yourRelativeLayouyt;
     mContainer.setLayoutParams(new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            mContainer.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            mContainer.requestFocus();
            mContainer.bringToFront();
    }
```

Comment: I actually want to detect orientation change when the video is playing. And since the entire screen has been restricted to Portrait only, I cannot detect the orientation change while video is playing. Any suggestion on that, will be great.

Comment: You may also create and manage your list of `videoviews` in a separate `class` extended from `Activity` , For Configuration Change Event , try

`<activity
    android:name=".VideoDetails"
    android:configChanges="orientation"/>

public class VideoDetails extends Activity {
    ...
    onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        // do stuff for orientation change.
    }
}`

Comment: Yeah I will try on that, but my ListView is in Fragment since I am using Tab layout. I will get back to on this. Thanks man.